# Получить номер недели в году из даты

Tags: java, дата, calendar

Есть ли у Java метод для определения номера недели по дате.
я нашел вот такой метод

```
return Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

но он возвращает текущую неделю. А мне нужно понять какая шла по счету неделя от начала года для произвольной даты.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
cal.setTime(sdf.parse("Mon Nov 6 16:02:37 GMT 2017"));
```

как мне понять что `Mon Nov 6 16:02:37 GMT 2017` это 45 неделя?

Comment: Наверное вызвать `cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);` :)

Comment: да сработало)))